# WPF: Drawing Bitmap - Access Violation?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapsource

My program is drawing the Bitmap Frames to WPF control as video.

The sample code is below:

```
while(true)
{
    mStream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream((unsigned char*)jpegBuff, jpegBuffLenght);
    JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(mStream, BitmapCreateOptions::PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption::Default);
    bitmapSource = decoder->Frames[0];
    myWPFControl.DrawImage(bitmapSource)
}
```

I encountered two problems with my code:

1) Sometimes it crash with the message `"Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program"` when run at line `JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(...)`

2) Sometime it crash with the message "Access Violation", and the Call Stack in this case is below:

[image]

Someone can tell me the problems in my code.

Thank you very much!

T&T

Comment: How big is the image? also is this meant to be tagged `c++` not `c#`

Comment: @sa_ddam213: I'm using managed code. This image is 1280x720, the size about 2,7MB/frame

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I think you should close the UnmanagedMemoryStream at the end of each loop.

Comment: You have an endless loop that constantly creates new objects. That's bound to cause memory issues

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually see memory pressure when you run your program?

I found that Bitmap-related classes throw OutOfMemoryException in cases that don't have much to do with being out of memory.  It is even documented: [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) throws OOM if the file format is supported..

Perhaps occasionally there really is a corrupt image in the stream that causes it to throw OOM?

If you do see memory pressure, this tread suggests that the managed objects are not GC'd in time in tight while loops:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/782d1eaa-a0f3-4b10-8775-01fcaa063997/wpf-draw-image?forum=wpf

However, calling GC.Collect() after each frame, as in the solution in the link, may not be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you!
I think that the case as you mentioned can occur: "Perhaps occasionally there really is a corrupt image in the stream that causes it to throw OOM?". So how to process if it is caused by a corrupt image?

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe you can catch that specific exception (however nasty it feels catching and suppressing OOM exception) and skip that frame, showing the previous one longer instead.